# How $\cos ^2\left(x\right)\sin ^2\left(x\right)=\frac{1-\cos \left(4x\right)}{8}$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

$$\cos ^2\left(x\right)\sin ^2\left(x\right)=\frac{1-\cos \left(4x\right)}{8}$$

$2\cos \left(x\right)\sin \left(x\right)=sin2x$

Comment: Look [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1352724/trig-identities-sin22t-and-frac1-cos4t2)

Answer (score 3):

Using $\;\cos2\alpha=\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha=1-2\sin^2\alpha\;$ , and $\;\sin2\alpha=2\cos\alpha\sin\alpha\;$ :

$$\frac{1-\cos4x}8=\frac{1-(\cos^22x-\sin^22x)}8=\frac{1-(1-2\sin^22x)}8=$$

$$=\frac{\sin^22x}4=\left(\frac{\sin2x}2\right)^2=\sin^2x\cos^2x$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin^2 x\cos^2 x = \frac{\sin^2 2x}{4} = \frac{1 - \cos 4x}{8}$$